# How to draw rectangle marker in leaflet given only 1 [lat,lon] pair

Tags: leaflet

I need to draw a rectangle around a point in leaflet map. the point is a [lat,lon] pair. How can I easily do that? I know its easy to draw a circle. But how can I draw a rectangle?

Comment: how are you determining the size/aspect ratio of the rectangle?

Comment: size is reasonable. may be 20 by 15

Comment: 20 by 15 what? Pixels? Meters?

Comment: 20 pixel by 15 pixel

Comment: Is it possible to give the values in meters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code figures out the coordinates for your rectangle then adds it to the map.

```
    var latLng = L.latLng(your_coordinates);
    var currentPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(latLng);
    var width = 20;
    var height = 15;
    var xDifference = width / 2;
    var yDifference = height / 2;
    var southWest = L.point((currentPoint.x - xDifference), (currentPoint.y - yDifference));
    var northEast = L.point((currentPoint.x + xDifference), (currentPoint.y + yDifference));
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds(map.containerPointToLatLng(southWest),map.containerPointToLatLng(northEast));
    L.rectangle(bounds).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Ok the problem solved. Thanks. But how can I change the fill and line color?

Comment: Manipulate the style in the options hash of `L.rectangle`.It's the second parameter(not used in my example.) http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle

Answer (score 1):

It is easier when you specify the radius in meters:

You can achieve that by doing:

1.- Get bounds with given center coordinates and radius:

```
let radiusMts = 5500;
let bounds = L.latLng(44.6730555555556, 6.9225).toBounds(radiusMts);
```

2.- Add bounds to reactangle:

```
L.rectangle(bounds).addTo(map);
```

Aditionally you can set a color to the rectangle:

```
L.rectangle(bounds, {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(map);
```

In other words, object 'bounds' is like a rectangle, so you will have the northeast, nortwest, southeast and soutwest coordinates.

More info: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#latlng